# Translating .unpack from Python 2.7 to 3.9

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I am working on rewriting a piece of code that was written for python 2.7. I am having trouble with the line below. It doesn't give any errors, but the self.gear value doesn't look right.

```
self.gear = struct.unpack("I", self.mm[64:68])[0]
```

Comment: There should be no difference from py2.7 to py3.x with this.

Answer (score 0):

`struct.unpack("I",some_bytes[0:4])` works exactly the same in py2 and py3